# Why "string" == ["string"] is true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I needed to iterate thought object and I'm losing my mind WIth this.

```js
var obj = { a:"here", b: ["here"]};
for(var o in obj){
  alert(obj[o]=="here");
  }
```

Comment: have you tried === instead of ==

Comment: Yep... I'm want to  know why == just don't work.

Comment: === will not do the type conversion

Comment: @AlvaroJoao: `==` does work. It works exactly [as the spec defines it.](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) If they behaved the same way, there would be no reason to have two different operators.

Comment: Setting aside why it is relevant, you can view the spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false. It's this case where === will be faster, and may return a different result than ==. In all other cases performance will be the same.

It should be using === instead of ==:

```
var obj = { a:"here", b: ["here"]};
for(var o in obj){
  alert(obj[o]==="here");
  }
```

Comment: I know that work around. I need to  know why == does not work

Comment: array ['a', 'b'] will convert to string like 'a,b'

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are comparing a string with an array by using the `==` operator. JavaScript interpreter converts the array into a string by calling the `Array.prototype.toString` method. The method calls the `Array.prototype.join` method behind the scenes.

```
["here"].toString() // => "here"
["here", "foo"].toString() // => "here,foo"
```